# Bootstrap datepicker clone not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use simple datepicker for twitter bootstrap http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Try to clone input tag and append into another div. First input tag datepicker works perfectly. But second one(cloned input tag) isn't working at all.

I tried with this code

```
<div class="first">
  <input type="text" class="form-control sandbox-container">
</div>

<br>

<div class="second">
</div>

$('.sandbox-container').datepicker({
});

$( ".sandbox-container" ).clone().appendTo( ".second" );
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41398/)

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.datepicker` as well to your clone.

```
$( ".sandbox-container" ).clone().appendTo( ".second" ).datepicker({
});
```

Comment: @krezus yes, on his jsfiddle.

Comment: It's working fine in fiddle, but it showing weird another calendar popup in my pc. I think it's default jquery calendar.

Comment: @CssSY that image is not loading for me. Try imgur.com, anyway if it's showing another calendar maybe something because of the order of your external files, like you have jquery first then bootstrap datepicker.